# What is this thing called? I'd like to recreate this one in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile-application

I'm a beginner Flutter developer and I've been developing few apps right now. I came across this chat bubble-like thing in few popular apps like Ola and Uber. Also, I'd like to recreate this feature in order to achieve background running of App.

How to recreate this one?

[image]

I guess this as an App widget that gets opened when a user closes the app.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create your own CustomWidget - a Container with Rounded shape and put some column of widgets you want to put it in. And use it everywhere you want.

Comment: No... Actually it doesn't exists inside the app... as soon as the user closes or minimizes the app, just like an chat bubble, this icon appears... ensuring that the app runs in background